# Trying to connect to university wifi doesnt work opens networking menu

Tags: networking, wireless, 16.04

I recently reinstalled ubuntu and am now running 16.04. I can connect to wifi networks fine, but with my university wifi network when I click on it from the wifi applet, it just opens up the networking menu and doesn't connect. Clicking connect from this menu gives the loading icon for a few seconds before stopping and not doing anything.
Any help hugely appreciated :D

when running

```
sudo lshw -class network
```

this is the output:

```
*-network               
  description: Wireless interface
  product: Centrino Advanced-N 6235
  vendor: Intel Corporation
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
  logical name: wlp1s0
  version: 24
  serial: c8:f7:33:10:5f:63
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
  configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-22-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=10.230.244.72 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
  resources: irq:29 memory:f0500000-f0501fff
*-network
  description: Ethernet interface
  product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
  vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
  logical name: enp2s0
  version: 06
  serial: 18:67:b0:df:1f:af
  size: 10Mbit/s
  capacity: 1Gbit/s
  width: 64 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
  configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
  resources: irq:25 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0404000-f0404fff memory:f0400000-f0403fff
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain you are using the appropriate connection settings in the networking menu?

For example, at my university, in addition to the username and password, the connection must be configured to use:

- WPA & WPA2 Enterprise
- EAP/PEAP
- MSCHAPv2

Comment: That's the thing, I can't even bring up any menu to configure it

Comment: I see. Try editing the connection: wifi applet icon -> edit connections (bottom) -> then select the appropriate network and hit edit. Perhaps some setting sneaked in there and is causing it to fail silently.